# Crossfilter scatterplot with 2-d brushing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter

I'm thinking about doing brushing on a scatterplot with [crossfilter](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/), and it's not exactly clear how to go about it; I've looked very carefully at [canonical example](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) and also Mike's [scatterplot matrix brushing](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063663) d3 code.

In particular, my problems are:

1. **Querying**: I'm not sure how to do a 2-d query to crossfilter. Should I just:

   a. Do 2 1-d queries and intersect the results myself?

   b. Make a single 2-d dimension (i.e. something like `data.dimension(function(d){ return [d.x, d.y];})`), and use a custom filter function on it?
2. **Performance**: It takes ~150ms to draw the scatter plot (vs ~10ms for a histogram). This makes live-updating (even if the query were fast), not great.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [DC.js](http://nickqizhu.github.io/dc.js/)?

DC.js is a Javascript charting library that extends D3.js and has [crossfilter](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) support. I just started using it for a bar chart, though I haven't tried it for a scatterplot yet. It allows you to filter and zoom in on subsets interactively, and it's fast with crossfilter.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would set up two dimensions in crossfilter - one for x and one for y - and let the crossfilter library intersect the results for you. Crossfilter does some fancy stuff behind the scenes that works better with one dimensional data. If you don't have much data and you only want the scatter plot filter, it might be easier to just copy the flower example:

   return e[0][0] > d[p.x] || d[p.x] > e[1](http://roadtolarissa.com/meteors/)[0]
         || e[0](http://roadtolarissa.com/meteors/) > d[p.y] || d[p.y] > e[1](http://roadtolarissa.com/meteors/);
2. Don't redraw the entire scatter plot! Looking at the flower example, the only thing that changes is the application of the 'hidden' class. If you're only updating the color of the points, it won't take 150 ms to update. Additionally, if you leave the plotted points in place, you can add cool [transition effects](http://roadtolarissa.com/meteors/)

Comment: thanks. I'm still a bit unclear on how to get crossfilter to intersect the results. Can you provide a code snippet to sketch out what you had in mind? Also, good point about the redraw; by just updating the class, drawing is a lot faster. However, that's not what the crossfilter example does, for whatever reason.

Comment: I lost the code snippit trying to post it as a comment, basically ctrl-f for 'cartoDbIds' in this file http://roadtolarissa.com/meteors/drawMap.js and look at the two blocks of code it is in for my solution while looking at the crossfilter api. 

The crossfilter example doesn't ever redraw individuals points, just histogram bars.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Querying**

   a. 2 1-d queries. Same as Adams comment. Crossfilter will be faster with one-dimensional data.
2. **Rendering**

Most of this I think has to do with the rendering more than the query itself. Adam gave some great points, but I'd like to offer some alternative sources:

Look into leveraging `d3.geom.quadtree` (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4343214). This would allow you to re-visualize only the points that are being impacted. This however, means that a query of the other dataset cannot change the (x, y) location of an individual point in the scatterplot; as you would have to reindex the quad tree.

Also, have you considered a different visualization technique? 
2d binning is a good technique to help avoid performance issues: http://vis.stanford.edu/projects/datavore/splom/